# converting a string to byte (unsigned char) array cpp

Tags: c++, hex

having real trouble with this simple issue.
I have a string like this:

```
std::string msg = "00 00 00 00 00 06 01 05 00 FF 00 00";
```

which i would like to:

```
unsigned char bbuffer[12] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If at all possible, I'd advise using a `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of an actual array.

Using that, I guess I'd do something like this:

```
std::istringstream buffer(msg);

std::vector<unsigned char> bbuffer;

unsigned int ch;
while (buffer >> std::hex >> ch)
    bbuffer.push_back(ch);
```

If you really insist on the array, you could do something like:

```
std::istringstream buffer(msg);

char bbuffer[12];

unsigned int ch;
for (int i=0; buffer >> std::hex >> ch; i++)
    bbuffer[i] = ch & 0xff;
```

But the vector is usually preferable.

Comment: I was so close! I'll get you next time ;)

Comment: great.thnx. i was using vector internally anyway