# C++ String to byteArray Convertion and Addition

Tags: c++, string, arrays

I have a string which I want to convert to a byteArray, and then I want this byteArray to be added to another byteArray, but **at the beginning of that byteArray**.

Let us say this is the string I have

```
  string suffix = "$PMARVD";
```

And this is the existing byteArray that I have (ignore the object there, it is a .proto object which is irrelevant now):

```
int size = visionDataMsg.ByteSize(); // see how big is it
char* byteArray = new char[size]; //create a bytearray of that size

visionDataMsg.SerializeToArray(byteArray, size); // serialize it
```

So what I want to do is something like this:

```
char* byteArrayforSuffix = suffix.convertToByteArray();
char* byteArrayforBoth = byteArrayforSuffix + byteArray;
```

Anyway of doing this in C++?

**Edit:** I should add that after the concatenation operation, the complete byteArrayforBoth is to be processed in:

```
// convert bytearray to vector
vector<unsigned char> byteVector(byteArrayforBoth, byteArrayforBoth + size);
```

Comment: Just use `std::string` and concat the strings.

Comment: Watch this if helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626749/converting-a-string-to-byte-unsigned-char-array-cpp

Comment: @PaoloM There aren't two strings, there is an object and a string. Both are to be converted into byteArrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the whole idea behind `std::string` is to wrap the C style strings (null terminated charcaters/bytes array) with a class that manages everything.

you can excess the inner characters array with `std::string::data` method. example :

```
std::string hello ("hello") , world(" world");
auto helloWorld = hello + world;
const char* byteArray = helloWorld.data();
```

EDIT:
ByteArray is a built-in type of `char[]` or `unsigned char[]`, unlike Java or C#, you can't just "append" built-in byte array to another. as you suggested, you simply want a vector of unsigned characters. in this situation I would simply create a utility-function that utilizes `push_back`:

```
void appendBytes(vector<unsigend char>& dest,const char* characterArray,size_t size){
    dest.reserve(dest.size() + size);
    for (size_t i=0;i<size;i++){
       dest.push_back(characterArray[i]);
    }
}
```

now , with the objects you provided:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> dest;
appendBytes(dest, suffix.data(),suffix.size());
auto another = visionDataMsg.SerializeToArray(byteArray, size); 
appendBytes(dest,another,size);
```

Comment: Why are you sprinkling your code with 'auto'? What good is it?

Comment: I wanted to sprinkle choclate and candies but stackoverflow won't let me. so I chose auto instead.

Comment: Avoid those as well as auto unless metaprogramming. Not good for your health, not good for your teeth, not good for your habits. Auto was invented for metaprogramming and iterating over containers (because you can't refer to a nested type through object instance, which is a defect in my view). In your example auto just confuses and obfuscates.

Comment: this is really not the appropriate place to talk about the useability of auto.

Comment: Why the `shrink_to_fit` call?

Comment: @SergeyA: `auto` was invented before metaprogramming. See http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#auto and http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/07/gotw-92-solution-auto-variables-part-1/.

Comment: @DavidHaim The `.data()` convertion is OK and it does convert the string into a byteArray, but you did not provide a way to concatanate two byteArrays,  which was the second part of the question; therefore I am unable to accept your answer. Could you tell me how can I concatanate these two byteArrays into one?

Comment: @ChristianHackl, if the function he's using accept size parameter, then it's redundand.  `shink_to_fit` will trim away any reserved memory that is not specificly the data he needs..

Comment: @DavidHaim: But the observable behaviour is the same. That is, the array returned by `data()` is required to be null-terminated anyway.

Comment: @DavidHaim auto prevents the compilation, is this feature some sort of a new thing? My compiler does not let it, oh do not tell me that this is some C11 stuff please?

Comment: yes, it's a C++11 feature. it's basically exands to the correct type according to the right side of the assignment. yo can replace it with const char*, if that what's SerializeToArray returns.

Answer (score 0):

Scrap built-in arrays.  You have vectors. Here is the fully working, type-safe  solution which took me 3 minutes to type:

```
int size = visionDataMsg.ByteSize(); // see how big is it
std::vector<char> byteArray(size);

visionDataMsg.SerializeToArray(&byteArray[0], size); // serialize it 

std::string str("My String");
byteArray.reserve(byteArray.size() + str.size());
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(byteArray));
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can change the parameter for the function `SerializeToArray()` ? Note that the function is coming from the proto files that were autogenerated by the protocol buffer stuff.

Comment: There is no change of parameter. SerializeToArray would not know a difference.

Comment: What is `myArray` btw? What is it there for?

Comment: Is there a way to stick to byteArray as I have to pass that to `vector<unsigned char> byteVector(byteArray, byteArray + size);` since eventually it will be passed this through some network function. When I follow the way you provided, it gives an error as we are not working with byteArray anymore, but rather vector; which is not suitable for that case.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I gave you a solution which works exactly the way you wanted to. Now, since you will be using vector anyways (byteVector) there is no need to have the byteArray altogether. Start with byteVector and do my code with it.

Comment: The problem is, I do not want to change the irrelevant parts of the complete code just to convert and add two things to each other, I mean, why can't we stick to byteArray, why does it have to be vector here, I don't get this necessity. I simply want to convert a string into a byteArray, and then concat this to another. Simple, straightforward. No sophisticated operation is needed, no improvement, nothing. Just this.